# Как быть, когда кто-то использует похожий домен и спамит ваших клиентов?

Tags: домен

Кто-то использует почти идентичный домен домену фирмы "Рога и копыта" (по электронной почте).

Этот некто позиционирует себя как представитель этой фирмы и просит клиентов перечислить деньги на счёт, указанный в счёте-фактуре, который выглядит как оригинальный, кроме непосредственно данных самого счета, на который будет произведён перевод средств, заявляя при этом, что товар, который они заказывали, был отправлен.

Надо полагать, что у самозванца имеется информация по электронным адресам клиентов, формат счетов-фактуры, которые использует компания и, вероятно, они каким-то образом знают формат переписки между офисом продаж и клиентами.

Какие действия следует предпринять в данной ситуации?

*Оригинал: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176963/someone-is-using-similar-domain-and-spamming-clients*
*(Автор: [aitkotw](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/167875/aitkotw))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте инструменты наподобие http://www.tcpiputils.com/ чтобы выяснить кто владеет мошенническим доменом, где он расположен, а также разузнайте адрес, с которого идёт спам. Затем пошлите администраторам несколько примеров таких мошеннических писем, с просьбой "погасить" поддельный домен, с целью предотвращения повторных рассылок спама. Это должно помочь во время их внутреннего расследования.

Кроме того, предупредите всех ваших клиентов о том, что на данный момент они могут стать жертвами такого рода обмана.

Также стоит уведомить о такого рода мошенничестве соответствующие правоохранительные органы в вашей стране.

*На основе: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176965/34818* *(Автор: [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder))*

Comment: Правоохранительные органы в нашей стране ничего не сделают, у них лапки. Эту часть можно было бы и не переводить.